# Configuring Server with no monitor

Tags: remote-access

Sitting in front of me is an HP DL 380 Generation 4 with no monitor. I'd like to install an OS on the thing but for reasons obvious, I can't. I got excited when I found the ILO port on the back but unless you have a subscription it has limited functionality. I was thinking maybe there was some software out there that booted into some kind of remote access server?

When I tested it with a monitor (A friends) I set the BIOS to boot from USB so anything I can load onto a stick should boot.

Ideas? Hacks?

Answer (score 1):

You can do console redirection from the BIOS if you plan on working with a text-based setup routine (like Linux). You need two computers with serial ports and an appropriate serial cable between them. Connect with hyperterm or putty or whatever on the other computer. Rocking it old school style!

Comment: That is old school! Un fortunately my current laptop has no serial connections.

Comment: USB to serial 'cables' (well, technically adapters) are cheap. And once the OS is set up you can use `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,9600` to get all console output on serial (skipping any special BIOS features)